# How to make online test of math with the available internet base tools?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask such a question! Please let me know if this is not!

I am going to make a test for the students of Calculus 1 at the university. The test contain 4 questions and will remain open for three days. The students need to solve the questions on paper and send me a photo of their solutions. When a student opens a question, he/she has one hour to solve the question, take a photo, convert to PDF and send it to me via the system. One of the questions should be about the integration techniques. I cannot give some integrals (simple or difficult) and ask them to solve it because anyone may use some available applications or websites (like [symbolab](https://symbolab.com/)) to find the solutions.

Anyone have any idea on what sort of questions I can ask on the integration's techniques in the test.

Any help is very welcome and appreciated in advance!

An idea of mine is to give the integral

$$ \int \frac{x}{x^2-1}dx$$
and ask them to solve the integral using three different techniques!

Comment: I can only suggest that you post questions that can be done with pencil and paper where a calculator might get precision but the idea can be conveyed symbolically. There will always be cheats like [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%5E2%2Bx%2B1) but they can be instructive too.

Comment: Yeah, I am going to make such a test, but the point is what kind of questions I can give that the student cannot simply find the step by step solutions on the internet and send to me! You may see the link I add as an comment to the answer below.

Comment: One such question might be "What are the steps required to integrate some variable raised to a non-negative power?" Only a  non-formula response would be acceptable such as, "Increase the variable power by one and then divide by the resulting power." They could still use Wolfram Alpha to figure it out but they would have to process it mentally to put it into words.

Comment: Perhaps integrals depending on a parameter? For example, in $\int \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}$, the computer might do only the case $a>0$, not $a<0$ and $a=0$: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%2Ba%5E%7B2%7D%7Ddx

Answer (score 0):

If it's Calculus 1, the AP Calculus AB (or BC) exams have Free Response Questions (FRQs). These FRQs are usually application-based, and justification or work is required for full credit. I don't know whether you would want to grade the justification or work shown, but it definitely prevents cheating using online solvers. Although there are sections that require a graphing calculator, these sections can be removed. Also, I would switch some of the numbers and/or formatting to prevent students from simply looking up answers to the AP Calculus FRQs.

As for integration techniques, for Calculus 1, I would limit the techniques to simpler ones, (u-substitution, integration by parts, trigonometric substitution, etc.), but it may be possible to allow for multiple steps requiring different techniques to solve. One simple example:

$$\int \frac {4x-2} {3x^2+4} dx$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as you may see the link below, any student can find the step by step answer through this website, write down it on a paper, send me a photo of it, and gain complete mark with no knowledge of math! https://pt.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B4x-2%20%7D%7B3x%5E%7B2%7D%2B4%7D%20%20dx